# React typescript remove `undefined` from props listed in default props

Tags: reactjs, typescript

## TLDR;

I want to implement a utility typescript function that receives 2 objects and removes undefined from props values in the first object of props keys that exist on the second object, so fat I tried:

```
type RespectDefaultProps<Props, defaultProps> = {
  [p in keyof Props]: p extends keyof defaultProps ? Exclude<Props[p], undefined> : Props[p];
};

type testRespectDefaultProps = RespectDefaultProps<{ name?: string; age?: number }, { age: number }>;
/**
type is:
{
    name?: string | undefined;
    age?: number | undefined;
}
but it should be:
{
    name?: string | undefined;
    age: number;
}
*/
```

`RespectDefaultProps` should work but I'm not sure why it doesn't.

[ts playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAShDOkDGwAiEBmBDArgG2AAUAnAezHgB4Tz4AaKAE01wJooD4oBeKAbwBQUKAG0wUAJYA7KAGsIIUhijt4AXQBcUcRAAewCFMbw5CpUxb4iZClAD8UAKK6keHM2o34YtQxxHMaQhGLi1VHwBuAQBfKIFQSCgDeGA4RAgUdGwrVR5YBGQ0SzYvSj4oKSwAWwg7LRTiaQBzCKgsJtqtKRwqgCMIYihohnL2iC6e-sHojiiAegAqBfjwaAl4DQFBYWFKmrqoBuaoAB8of2YMIMYonbaOg+6+gdPzgKupYKjogV6cYEkAPgAAtSPhGFB+pttjs9p1DsBGlImq8LoFPjchDsxhNnsRvgIFnMoAIgA)

### Details

when a component has an optional property, it's received from value type from the user may be undefined(not given). however, if defaultProp is given for this prop, its value inside the component would never be undefined(unless the user would pass explicitly undefined).

```
interface CompProps {
  name?: string;
  age?: number;
}

const Comp: React.FC<CompProps> = (props) => {
  props.age // number | undefined (when the wanted type is number)
  // age won't be undefined, because if it's undefined, the default prop for age will be used
  return <></>
};
Comp.defaultProps = {
  age: 25,
};
```

it can be fixed by using a utility type function that removes undefined from props listed in defaultProps.

```
interface CompProps {
  name?: string;
  age?: number;
}

const Comp: React.FC<CompProps> = (_props) => {
  const props = _props as RespectDefaultProps<CompProps,typeof CompDefaultProps>
  props.age // number -> That's is the wanted type
  return <></>
};

type RespectDefaultProps<Props, defaultProps> = ... //todo

const CompDefaultProps = {
  age: 25,
};
Comp.defaultProps = CompDefaultProps
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I came up with this solution that works great for me:

```
// hack to make the type expanded - somtimes this is wanted behavior
type Expand<T> = T extends infer O ? { [K in keyof O]: O[K] } : never;
// make PS keys be subset of keys of P, with no extra props
type PickValidKeys<P, PS> = Exclude<keyof P, Exclude<keyof P, keyof PS>>

type RespectDefaultProps<Props, DefaultProps extends { [rkey in keyof Props]: any }> = Expand<Props & {
  [Property in PickValidKeys<Props, DefaultProps>]-?: Exclude<Props[Property], undefined>;
}>;

type Props = { name?: string; age?: number }
type defaultProps = { age: number }
type testRespectDefaultProps = RespectDefaultProps<{ name?: string; age?: number }, { age: number }>;
/**
type testRespectDefaultProps = {
    name?: string | undefined;
    age: number;
}
// awsome!
 */
```

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PTAEAsEMGMGtQC4HtQFtKwKaPNhBPAB20wA9DIA7AE02tAFpQBnJVBAS1U2Zw9-6gA7lQR1QAI0xQAbhyQAnAFAFioAKLkq1ADwAVAHygAvKD2gyYmgMoAzTAtAB5UAH5QAb1ABtANKgOSlAsfCRbZwBdAC5nPwjQAF9QGMpMGQcAbiUQNAxsAAUAZWDMfF4pFgBXCWZMBFAwkrKG8PyAGmEOBHBQShRLBUhQQgUkQmYVIgKOOAA1SAAbDmpfUuYddtAio1NNaAXK2h0Qxs29g6OT1o6rrcKDAyVJtQAlHmJoBAARTFtISoWCHyo3GGxBzA6Pz+AKB4IspCs1F4Xm8ChCASCt2BY2Y0VAVHwiR2Gi0NDBONAADJPEpQD5scQFAQMVsZrB5ksVmtyeNIb9-oCGcwDBEGK4YudDpgecxvAyHAQIh1KjRfoE6AYsglNU9VAU4aYvJRINxxSwEApAgBzDL4q2YM2USqoKSOBLPbC0aGCg2eO2YFLO12JD2IHgIN7MD7ffkwoUmUCR6NQgWwnE6I0mh0xZgW622yD2x1BhyJDpeQsB3olt064AAKnrobEuaTmE+Kbjvo8tLpvSzZtzlsoVtAAB9QCqverqFk+-7Ay7Mkp3TlIEJWNwAIS0+vAJRAA)

### update

better utility (simpler to understand, simpler gnerated type):

```
export type RespectDefaultProps<Props, DefaultProps extends { [key in keyof Props]: any }> = {
  [p in keyof Required<Props>]: p extends keyof DefaultProps ? NonNullable<Props[p]>: Props[p];
};
```