# typescript React.FC how to express difference between given props(from user) to final props inside the component

Tags: reactjs, typescript

the props available inside component `Comp` can potentially be different from what the user passed to the component. I can think of 2 such scenarios:

- when using defaultProps: for example:

  ```
  import React, { FC } from "react";

  interface CompProps {
    name?: string;
  }
  const Comp: FC<CompProps> = (props) => {
    return <div>{props.name.toUpperCase()}</div>;
    //           ^ TS2532: Object is possibly 'undefined'.
  };
  Comp.defaultProps = {
    name: "",
  };
  ```

  the prop `name` is optional so `props.name` could be undefined, but because `name` has default prop it will never be undefined(unless `undefined` be passed explicitly) ([possible solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72645507/10577976))
- when props are injected from parents using `React.cloneElement`. props may be implicitly passed from parent to children without typescript knowing it.

currently, in order to fix this, I create another interface `FinalCompProps` which will contain the actual final props, and then casting it into `props`.

```
import React, { FC } from "react";

interface CompProps {
  name?: string;
}
interface FinalCompProps {
  name: string;
}

const Comp: FC<CompProps> = (_props) => {
  const props = _props as FinalCompProps // casting
  return <div>{props.name.toUpperCase()}</div>; // no errors
};
Comp.defaultProps = {
  name: "",
};
```

This works fine, but I wondered, there is no way to pass into React.FC expected type from the user and final props actually passed to the component?

Looking at the type definition React.FC

```
type FC<P = {}> = FunctionComponent<P>;

interface FunctionComponent<P = {}> {
  (props: P, context?: any): ReactElement<any, any> | null;
  propTypes?: WeakValidationMap<P> | undefined;
  contextTypes?: ValidationMap<any> | undefined;
  defaultProps?: Partial<P> | undefined;
  displayName?: string | undefined;
}
```

It looks like there is no option pass such 'FinalProps', and typescript will always end auto-suggest the props passed into React.FC when passing props to `Comp`

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest solution to this is:

```
props.name?.toUpperCase()
```

Then if `name` is undefined, it won't call `toUpperCase()`.

The point of Typescript is to define the types so you don't want to change the prop types.

What do you want to happen if `name` is undefined?